# How to Read values from XML file

Tags: c#

I have a XML document called RESTORE.XML
It hold these values..

```
<EmployeeDetails>
  <EmployeeID>156824</EmployeeID>
  <EmployeeName>ALEX</EmployeeName>
  <EmployeeAge>29</EmployeeAge>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

From my c# application i want to read these three values and store it in 3 different variables.

How can do it using c# ? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("RESTORE.XML");
xdoc.Descendants("EmployeeID").First().Value;
xdoc.Descendants("EmployeeName").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"
<EmployeeDetails>
  <EmployeeID>156824</EmployeeID>
  <EmployeeName>ALEX</EmployeeName>
  <EmployeeAge>29</EmployeeAge>
</EmployeeDetails>");

            int EmployeeID = int.Parse(xml.Element("EmployeeID").Value);
            string EmployeeName = xml.Element("EmployeeName").Value;
            int EmployeeAge = int.Parse(xml.Element("EmployeeAge").Value);
```

but replace the parse with a load of your xml file instead...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that in our example we have a xml with root node Reports and there are nested child nodes Reports and we need to loop through each child

> sample.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Reports>
  <Report>
    <Code>CP</Code>
    <RepeatStyle>Weekly</RepeatStyle>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Code>USS</Code>
    <Name>User Snapshot</Name>
    <RepeatStyle>Monthly</RepeatStyle>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Code>USS</Code>
    <Name>Failed Logon Report</Name>
    <RepeatStyle>Monthly</RepeatStyle>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Code>USS</Code>
    <Name>Failed Logon Report</Name>
    <RepeatStyle>Monthly</RepeatStyle>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

Here we can make use of System.Xml.XmlDocument which we used to read the Xml file given in the target location and System.Xml.XmlNodeList to pick up the certain nodes

```
XmlDocument serverDoc = new XmlDocument();
serverDoc.Load("sample.xml");
XmlNodeList xml = serverDoc.SelectNodes("Reports/Report");

foreach (XmlNode node in xml)
{
      var code = node.SelectSingleNode("Code").InnerText;
      var repeatStyle = node.SelectSingleNode("RepeatStyle").InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("restore.xml" );
foreach (XmlNode nd in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes( "xml/entry" ))
{
...
}
```